# How can I work Object.map((e){ print(e)}) in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm coding as following with using `map method` but it doesn't work, actually it means that nothing is printed on console.
Is it problem of the way of using map() or async-await, and how can I work it ?

```
onPressed: () async {
    // final insertLists =[
    // IconList(
    // iconPass: "images/icons/map.png", 
    // status: 1, 
    // memo: "nothing",
    // createdAt: DateTime.now(), 
    // title: 'XXX',
    // subTitle: 'YYY',
    // ),
    // IconList(
    // iconPass: "images/icons/cheer.png", 
    // status: 1, 
    // memo: "nothing",
    // createdAt: DateTime.now(), 
    // title: 'AAA',
    // ),

    List<IconList> lists = await DbHelper.instance.selectAllIcons();
    lists.map((e){
    print(e);
    });
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do a print using `.map()`.

Instead you can print it as follows :

```
List<IconList> lists = await DbHelper.instance.selectAllIcons();

for(var i in lists) {
  print(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! is that just specification of dart ? I know that there are map method in other languages such as JavaScript but never heard that print(), console.log() is not allowed to use in their body.